# Using cell arrays and getting too many input arguments error

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, cell

I'm a beginner in MATLAB.  I have my function `testnetwork`:

```
function result = TestNetwork(network, input)
result = input;
 b= [-1 -1 -1 -1 ];
      % Iterate over all the couches
      for i=1:length(network.couches)
      result = network.activation(matrix_multiplication_same_dimension(network.couches{i} ,  vertcat ( result , b))); 
      end
end
```

and this is my main script:

```
% initialis a cell of zeros for example   output = zeros_quat(zeros(1, 2)) is %equal to   [0 0 0 0]    [0 0 0 0]
 output = zeros_quat(zeros(10, size(testset,2)));
% 
 for i = 1:size(testset, 2)
%testset is a cell of arrays size (81 * 180)
    output {:,i} = TestNetwork(network, testset{:,i});
 end
end
```

I get the error `too many input arguments`.  I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Your problem is `testset{:,i}`.  This would produce a comma-separated list of 180 elements.  This means that you're trying to feed your function with 180 + 1 inputs. I have no idea what `testset{:,i}` is actually supposed to be so I can't comment on what you're trying to do.  Also, `output{:,i}` will give you an error once you fix the `testset{:,i}` problem.

Comment: @rayryeng exactly i want to load  181  because couche.netwok is a matrix and  matrix_multiplication_same_dimension multiply 2 matrix

Comment: result=network.activation(matrix_multiplication_same_dimension(network.couches{i} ,  vertcat ( result , b)));                                                            matrix_multiplication_same_dimension this function multiply 2 matrix of quaternion , @rayryeng

Comment: quaternion is a hyper complex number where q = a +ib +cj+dk  so in matlab we express a quaternion like this for exemple q = [               1 2 3 4 ]  so if we need  matrix of quaternions it will be like that m = [1 2 3 4] , [5 6 7 8] ; [9 10 11 12] [ 13 14 15 16 ], this is a 2*2 matrix.   that why the matrix is a cell of arrays. so in my main function  i need to loas test {: , i} not element by element in order to multply 2 matrix  @rayryeng

Comment: @AmalKostaliTarghi: we understand what quaternions are, but I think perhaps you don't realize that a *single cell* of a cell array can contain a matrix of whatever dimension you like.  But even disregarding that, you can easily manipulate columns of data with regular matrices, you would not need cell arrays for that.

Comment: @gariepy  how can manipulate ( charge) column by column without using {:,1}

Comment: With regular matrices: `output = zeros(10, 2);  output(:,1) = ones(10,1);`

Comment: @gariepy thank you it works and u can get the output of my quaternionic neural network

Comment: @AmalKostaliTarghi: I'm glad that works.  Did you mean to unaccept the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is the problem:

```
output {:,i} = TestNetwork(network, testset{:,i});
```

When you de-reference the cell array `testset` using curly braces `{}` with multiple entries, it takes the individual cells of the cell array and returns all of them as separate arguments:

```
a = { [ 1 2], [3 4] };
a{1}
ans =
     1     2

a{1,:}
ans =
     1     2
ans =
     3     4
```

Note the two instances of `ans` in the second evaluation.  I suspect that what you really want is a reference to a single cell on both sides of the equation:

```
output{i} = TestNetwork(network, testset{i});
```

Comment: result = network.activation(matrix_multiplication_same_dimension(network.couches{i} ,  vertcat ( result , b)));

Comment: result = network.activation(matrix_multiplication_same_dimension(network.couches{i} ,  vertcat ( result , b)));   network.couche is a cell array and i need to multiply 2 cell array like multiplication of 2 matrix so i need to load column by column and not element by element

Comment: the function matrix_multiplication_same_dimension multiply 2 matrix of array ( for quaternions)